# Как при записи в БД sqlite одновременно читать?

Tags: java, sqlite

Есть 2 класса: один пишет данные в таблицу, второй одновременно читает. При текущей реализации выдает "**java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)**". Подскажите как решить проблему?

```
class Main  
{  
  public static void  main( String[] args )  
  {  
    DB.connect();

    for( int i = 0; i <= 100; i++ )    
         DB.write( "Table", "text", "" + i );  

    new Thread( new Reader() ).start();  
    new Thread( new Writer() ).start();  

  }

}
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
class Writer implements Runnable  
{  
    @Override  
    public void run()  
    {  
      for( int i = 100; i <= 200; i++ )    
         DB.write( "Table", "text", "" + i );  
    }  
}
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
class Reader implements Runnable  
{  
    @Override  
    public void run()  
    {  
      for( int i = 0; i <= 100; i++ )    
         System.out.println( DB.readString( "Table", i, "text" ) );  
    }  
}
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
class DB  
{  
 static Connection conn;    
 static ResultSet resSet;   

 public static void connect()   
 {  
   try   
   {  
     String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db.data";  
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);  
   }  
   catch (SQLException e) {}
  }

 public static void write( String nameTable, String field, String value )  
 {  
    try  
    {  
        conn.createStatement().execute( "INSERT INTO '"  
                + nameTable + "' ("  + field  + ") VALUES ("  
                + value  + "); ");  
    }  
    catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }  
 } 

public static String  readString( String nameTable, int index, String field)  
   {  
     String data = "";  

        try  
        {  
          resSet = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT " + field +" 
                   FROM " + nameTable + " WHERE " + "ID=" + index + ";");

            data = resSet.getString( field ) ;    
        }  
        catch (SQLException e) {}  

        return data;  
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Изначально SQLite проектировалась как встроенная БД. Архитектура разделения одновременного доступа к данным была устроена примитивно: одновременно несколько соединений могут читать БД, а вот записывать в данный момент времени может только одно соединение. Это, как минимум, означает, что пишущее соединение ждет «освобождения» БД от читающих. При попытке записать в «занятую» БД приложение получает ошибку SQLITE_BUSY.

В режиме WAL ([Write-Ahead Logging](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)) «читатели» БД и «писатели» в БД уже не мешают друг другу, то есть допускается модификация данных при одновременном чтении. Короче говоря, это шаг в сторону больших и серьезных СУБД, в которых все так и есть. Утверждается также, что SQLite в WAL работает быстрее.

Но есть и недостатки:

- требуется некоторые дополнительные ништяки от ОС (unix и Windows имеют эти ништяки);
- БД занимает несколько файлов (файлы «XXX-wal» и «XXX-shm»);
- плохо работает на больших транзакциях (условно, если транзакция больше 50 Мбайт);
- нельзя открыть такую БД в режиме «только чтение»;
- возникает дополнительная операция checkpoint.

Фактически, в режиме WAL данные БД разделяются между БД и файлом журнала. Операция checkpoint переносит данные в БД. По умолчанию, это делается автоматически, если журнал занял 1000 страниц БД.
© [Хабрахабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149635/)

В режим WAL базу можно попробовать перевести выполнением команды `PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL` сразу после открытия соединения:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только помогло вот так:                                            
   SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
   config.setPragma( SQLiteConfig.Pragma.JOURNAL_MODE, "WAL" ); 
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection( url, config.toProperties() );